# jaxb2-maven-plugin to report problems on Console

Tags: java, maven, jaxb2, jaxb2-maven-plugin, schemagen

I have a maven-based build script that runs jaxb2-maven-plugin (schemagen) to generate XSD from Java classes. I have done something wrong and it won't generate it.

The project is very complex and it is difficult to re-create in console the exact command line.

In my .pom file I just have

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>schemagen</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schemagen</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

What options I may use to command schemagen / plugin to show what was the cause of error on console?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your question**

1. I didn't find anything wrong in your POM.xml file, as I used the same POM file and it is generating the required schema at my target directory.
2. Please find the Domain Object user and I have generated XSD schema.

   ```
                   /**
                * 
                */
               package com.example;

               /**
                * @author Praveen
                *
                */
               public class User {

                   private String ename;
                   private String designation;
                   public String getEname() {
                       return ename;
                   }
                   public void setEname(String ename) {
                       this.ename = ename;
                   }
                   public String getDesignation() {
                       return designation;
                   }
                   public void setDesignation(String designation) {
                       this.designation = designation;
                   }

               }
   ```
3. POM file

   ```
                           <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                         <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                         <groupId>org.app</groupId>
                         <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
                         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                         <build>
                         <plugins>
                         <plugin>
                                   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                   <version>1.6</version>
                                   <executions>
                                       <execution>
                                           <id>schemagen</id>
                                           <goals>
                                               <goal>schemagen</goal>
                                           </goals>
                                       </execution>
                                   </executions>
                                   <configuration>
                                       <includes>
                                           <include>**/*.java</include>
                                       </includes>
                                   </configuration>
                               </plugin>
                         </plugins>

                         </build>



                       </project>
   ```
4. Maven Goals as

   > clean install -e
5. Output on my IDE, please refer below figure.

[image: schema generation]

[image: schem gen]

6. Please refer [these](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html) example from this link